# c# SQL max pool size was reached

Tags: c#, sql, connection-pooling

I have a simple while loop that checks the database for inserts. If its in the loop too long my try catch gets "max pool size was reached" error. So at the bottom of loop I have a connection`clearallpools()`; But that still doesn't solve it.

```
while (!quit)
{
connection to database strings timeout=400

read from database


connection.clearallpools();
}
```

Comment: Break your statements up into batches. Hitting the maximum pool size is a Very Bad Thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably **keep opening new connections in the loop**.

Above the loop open the connection is a `using` statement and then use it in the loop. Also note the **removal** of the `clearallpools`:

```
using(create new connection)
{
    while (!quit)
    {
    connection to database strings timeout=400

    read from database


    // connection.clearallpools(); REMOVE THIS!!!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are not closing your connections...you may want to use

```
while(!quit){
    //do something here
    using(var connection = GetMyConnection()){
        //do your db reads here
    }
    //do validations and something more here
}
```

This would ensure your connections are disposed / closed properly.

Also, you do not need to clear your pools.

SQLConnection / DBConnection objects implements IDisposable. You may want to go thru these

- [Digging into IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx)
- [C# Using Statement with SQL Connection](http://blog.amitmathur.in/index.php/2009/11/17/c-using-statement-try-finally-idisposable-dispose-sqlconnection-sqlcommand/)

Answer (score 0):

You're exhausting the connection pool. Following each read you should close the connection which will release it back to the pool.